# Multicolour Text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, sigabrt

Can you please help me, I tried to make multicolour text but I get a SIGABRT error but absolutely don't know from were it comes from. Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    

@IBOutlet weak var ColoredTxt: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: ColoredTxt, selector: Selector("ColoredTxt"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


@IBAction func Btn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let redValue = CGFloat(drand48())
    let greenValue = CGFloat(drand48())
    let blueValue = CGFloat(drand48())

    ColoredTxt.textColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)
}


func randomColor() {

    let redValue = CGFloat(drand48())
    let greenValue = CGFloat(drand48())
    let blueValue = CGFloat(drand48())

    ColoredTxt.textColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)

    }
}
```

Comment: where is `ColoredTxt` function ?

Comment: For Mutlicolored text you are supposed to you nsmutableattributed string

Comment: If you want have multiple colors in your label you need to use AttributtedString instead of textColor

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this, using `NSMutableAttributedString` allow you do things like this

[image]

Here is the code

```
   func multicolorString(originalString : String) ->NSMutableAttributedString
    {
        let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString)

        for index in 0..<originalString.characters.count
        {
            if(index % 2 == 0)
            {
                mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.green, range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
            }else if(index % 3 == 0)
            {
                mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
            }else{
                mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
            }
        }

        return mutableString
    }
```

and then use like this

```
self.ColoredTxt.attributedText = self.multicolorString("Owner")
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've got a little question: Where do you put the 'then you use like this'  piece of code ?

Comment: @iTiph078_ you can use this on your button action and you can also replace the colors by your random colors as well

Answer (score -1):

```
func getAttribute(_ array: [[String: UIColor]]) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "" )

    for item in array {
        let text = item.keys.first ?? ""
        let color = item.values.first ?? UIColor.black
        let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color])
        attributedString.append(attributed)
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

Usage:

```
let attributedString = getAttribute([["H" : UIColor.black], ["i" : UIColor.gray]])
button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me ☹️. I get an error saying "Use of the local variable 'getAttribute' before its declaration"

Comment: @iTiph078_ can you show me your code because it works for me