# How to display 2 labels dynamically with different color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

[image]

See in Image, in that message "I still look back on that expe...." and after that one count value is there i.e (7) .

Here, message color is blue and count value i.e (7) is in green color.

My question is that, how to adjust both labels dynamically with different length and different color like example shown in image.

Comment: You can use NSLayoutConstraint for that...

Comment: NSAttributedString you can use it for this

Comment: provide your tryed code

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306760/multicolour-text-in-swift/42306953#42306953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString` like in this example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I still look back on that expe.... (7)"];
[string setColorForText:@"I still look back on that expe...." withColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[string setColorForText:@"(7)" withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
mylabel.attributedText = string;
```

Or you can use the constraints in storyboard.
It is simple, you must use the `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority` values to reduce the first label to attach to the other label.

If you want I can explain you in detail how to do it.

**EDIT:**

You can try this code:

```
NSString *firstPart = @"I still look back on that expe....";
NSString *secondPart = @"(7)";

NSAttributedString *firstAttrStr  = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:firstPart attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor] }];
NSAttributedString *secondAttrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:secondPart attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor] }];

NSMutableAttributedString* result = [firstAttrStr mutableCopy];
[result appendAttributedString:secondAttrStr];

self.label.attributedText = result;
```

To add the images you can use `NSTextAttachment`.

Comment: Your updated code working dynamically for me. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with two labels is not the way you want to do it. A much better solution would be to use `NSAttributedString`.

```
struct MyMsg {
        var text: String
        var count: Int
    }

    let msg = MyMsg(text: "I still look back on that expe....", count: 7)

    let contentString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: msg.text)
    let countString = NSAttributedString(string: " \(msg.count)", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green])
    contentString.append(countString)
    myLabel.attributedText = contentString
```

Comment: can you please explain ur code in Objective c ? I dont know Swift.